# how to access UNICODE_STRING CommandLine variable?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process, command-line-arguments

I found out that the command line arguments for a program run in windows are stored in Process Environment block.I found out more that inside PEB there is a structure called RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS , which holds a member variable named UNICODE_STRING CommandLine;
can i access this variable by writing a c code ? please assist 
For more information about PEB refer this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813706%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: do we need any header file for this >?which one >?

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`GetCommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  Even if your program is ANSI, you can still explicitly call the wide version, `GetCommandLineW`.

This function is [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Look in the Requirements section and you'll see that it is defined in `WinBase.h` but that you should include `Windows.h`.  It is only available starting with Windows XP, so depending on the version of the SDK that you're using you might need to define [`_WIN32_WINNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: Actually, GetCommandLine has been available since Windows NT 3.1, but MSDN documentation goes back only to XP.

Comment: I am afraid of messing with the PEB now ,i thought the other way around . Now my view is ...assume there is a call to the main of a program (i know the point where main is being called lets say its _START), then is it possible to say tht the arguments are stored at exactly x address space before main is being called . for example main is called at address 5000 ...can we say every time that the address of the arguments are at position 4500 of the memory. ?

Comment: @archies50 Just call GetCommandLine to get the command line. Why are you trying to do things the extra-hard way?